# Query shows count of 0 even though there are records in the database

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query which inserts into a table the HS_Reps that did not complete an inspection last month (indicated by a rowcount = 0). Here is the code and associated tables:

```
DELETE
FROM `not_complete`
WHERE 1 = 1;

INSERT INTO `not_complete`
(ID 
,HS_Rep
,rowcount
,HS_Rep_Email)

SELECT p.ID
      ,p.HS_Rep
      ,COUNT(i.Lead_Inspector)
      ,e.Email

FROM projects p

LEFT JOIN employee e
ON p.HS_Rep = e.Lastname_Firstname
LEFT JOIN inspections i
ON p.HS_Rep = i.Lead_Inspector

AND year(i.date) = year(curdate())
AND month(i.date) = month(curdate()) -1
AND i.Type_of_Inspetion = HS_Rep_Monthly

WHERE p.active = "Yes"
GROUP BY p.HS_Rep
HAVING COUNT(i.Lead_Inspector) <1;
```

inspections i:

```
+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Lead_Inspector |      DATE       | Type_of_Inspection |
+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Bryant, Kobe   | August 1, 2019  | HS_Rep_Monthly     |
| James, Lebron  | August 15, 2019 | HS_Rep_Monthly     |
+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

projects p:

```
+----+-----------------+--------+
| ID |     HS_Rep      | Active |
+----+-----------------+--------+
|  1 | Bryant, Kobe    | Yes    |
|  2 | James, LeBron   | Yes    |
|  3 | Jordan, Michael | Yes    |
+----+-----------------+--------+
```

employee e:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
| Lastname_Firstname |       Email       |
+--------------------+-------------------+
| Bryant, Kobe       | kobe@email.com    |
| James, LeBron      | leBron@email.com  |
| Jordan, Michael    | michael@email.com |
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Using the code above I get the following result in the `not_complete` table:

```
+----+-----------------+----------+-------------------+
| ID |     HS_Rep      | rowcount |   HS_Rep_Email    |
+----+-----------------+----------+-------------------+
|  1 | Bryant, Kobe    |        0 | kobe@email.com    |
|  2 | James, LeBron   |        0 | lebron@email.com  |
|  3 | Jordan, Michael |        0 | michael@email.com |
+----+-----------------+----------+-------------------+
```

Even though there are some HS_Reps that completed an inspection last month, their rowcount is still shows up as 0.

Please let me know what changes need to be made to the code so that the appropriate rowcount appears and only those that did not complete an inspection appear in `not_complete`.

Comment: As you are using GROUP BY in a invalid way.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I tried removing the line with the GROUP BY function, but only one HS_Rep shows with a rowcount of 0, even though their rowcount is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the query can't 'understand' your date value.Try this:

```
SELECT p.ID
      ,p.HS_Rep
      ,COUNT(i.Lead_Inspector)
      ,e.Email

FROM projects p

LEFT JOIN employee e
ON p.HS_Rep = e.Lastname_Firstname
LEFT JOIN inspections i
ON p.HS_Rep = i.Lead_Inspector

AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(i.date,',',''), "%M %d %Y")) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(i.date,',',''), "%M %d %Y")) = MONTH(CURDATE())-1
AND i.Type_of_Inspetion = 'HS_Rep_Monthly'

WHERE p.active = "Yes"
GROUP BY p.HS_Rep
HAVING COUNT(i.Lead_Inspector) <1;
```

Observe this part:

```
AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(i.date,',',''), "%M %d %Y")) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(i.date,',',''), "%M %d %Y")) = MONTH(CURDATE())-1
```

First I removed the comma using `REPLACE` function for the date to become `August 1 2019`. Then with that format I use the `STR_TO_DATE` to change from `August 1 2019` to `2019-08-01`. So the end result will take year as 2019 and month as 08. Your previous query return `YEAR` and `MONTH` as `NULL`, that's why it doesn't work.